# Wrapping my HashTable class

Tags: python, wrapper, python-decorators

I need to be able to wrap a HashTable class. After reading about wrappers I am pretty sure this is a bad usage of a wrapper, however it is in my assignment. ( I have different data structures that need to be easily swapped in a program)

I have the following code:

```
from HashTable import HashTable

class HashTableWrapper(HashTable):

    def __init__(self, probe, size):
        super().__init__(probe, size)

    def tableInsert(self, searchKey, newItem):
        return self.HashTable.tableInsert(searchKey, newItem)

    def tableRetrieve(self, searchKey):
        return self.HashTable.tableRetrieve(searchKey)

    def tableDelete(self, searchKey):
        return self.HashTable.tableDelete(searchKey)
```

When I use:

```
x = HashTableWrapper("linearProbe", 100)
```

Everything is fine however, if I would use the following:

```
x.tableInsert(4, 6)
```

I get the following error: AttributeError: 'HashTableWrapper' object has no attribute 'HashTable'
I think something is wrong with the return part since python also highlights all the HashTable parts.
Some help would be appreciated.

Edit: I got the following example:

```
class BSTTableWrapper:
   def tableInsert(item):
       return self.bst.searchtreeInsert(item)
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have a `HashTable` attribute - you haven't *composed* to build a wrapper, you've *inherited*. It should just be e.g. `self.tableInsert(searchKey, newItem)`. But then the question becomes: what's the point of the wrapper?

Comment: When I try to insert an item now I get:  [Previous line repeated 995 more times] RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. 

I think the point is that my hashtable, binarysearchtree, 2-3-4tree etc all their similar functions will have the same names because of the wrappers. So if I want to switch to a different structure I can just import another wrapper but all the function names will stay the same. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, yes, if you just call it on `self` you'll get a never-ending recursion. You need `super().tableInsert(...)`, to call the parent class version of the method, just like you have in `__init__`. And if the wrapper interface is identical to the parent interface, there's really no benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your help it seems to work now. I have to use it now for previously mentioned reason. However would you say this is normally a bad use of a wrapper?

Comment: Pointless, rather than bad. If the idea is that you'd have multiple implementations with the same interface, then that's more sensibly handled with an abstract base class they all inherit.

Answer (score -1):

`self.HashTable` is never initialized so calling `self.HashTable.<function or variable>` would never work. If the HashTable object has the method `tableInsert`, then all you have to do is

```
def tableInsert(self, searchKey, newItem):
    return self.tableInsert(searchKey, newItem)

def tableRetrieve(self, searchKey):
    return self.tableRetrieve(searchKey)

def tableDelete(self, searchKey):
    return self.tableDelete(searchKey)
```

because the functions/methods are inherited from the HashTable.